# i got this message on emulator when i execute google maps . This app won't run unless you update google play services

Tags: android

On LogCat i got warning "Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4323000 but found 3136110".
i have tried all the solutions and use the  apk files suggested on stackoverflow . But still got this message. please Help

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong. You will need to update the Google Play Services via the Android SDK Manager. Also, post the solutions you have tried.

Comment: i have updated it but can't see map on emulator

Comment: Also, ensure your Android SDK and ADT versions are exactly the same. For example, if you install Android SDK v22.6.2, you must also install ADT v22.6.2.

Comment: It happend with me also, In my case I tried this way...
you need to update your google play services jar and then need to clean and build your project after adding it to your project. Also dont forget to check in manifest for minimum sdk version. After doing this you need to restart your editor( Eclipse or Studio).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update google play service library, Open your SDK manager and

[image]

You will get screen like this, select google play services from extras just check mark it and select install packages and update it.

Comment: Thank you. But i have already update Google play services in extras

Comment: Then try to clean and rebuild your project, and if you are running in device then uninstall the app and install after cleaning. Check what happens.

Comment: you need to update your google play services jar and then need to clean and build your project after adding it to your project. Also dont forget to check in manifest for minimum sdk version. After doing this you need to restart your editor( Eclipse or Studio).

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the same message yesterday, but my emulator updated Google play services via play store.

I had to install 'google play services' on my emulator via a zip file, I was following this guide: https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Maps-Fragment-Guide

Comment: This should not be posted as answer, but rather a comment.

Comment: Ah, I see. I forgot how much restriction you have when you first joined. ;)

Comment: anyway, I had to install 'google play services' on my emulator via a zip file, I was following this guide:  https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Maps-Fragment-Guide

Comment: Post this new comment as your answer instead. That way, you won't get the downvotes.